# Display same result set as combined for Two different Criteria on Max Id in SQL Server, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display same result set as combined for two different criteria on max id in SQL server.

Data Table:

| **Id** | **Hospital** | **RecNum** | **FUpTime** | **FollowUpDate** | **FUType** | **Diagnosis** | **Loction** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | x | 12c | 6 Weeks | 14/03/2017 | Call | Side Effects | 1 |
| 18 | y | 16a | 6 Weeks | 14/03/2017 | Call | No Complaints | 2 |
| 26 | x | 12c | 6 Weeks | 10/09/2018 | Clinic | Side Effects | 1 |
| 27 | y | 16a | 6 Weeks | 22/11/2018 | Clinic | No Complaints | 2 |
| 31 | y | 16a | 6 Months | 15/06/2019 | Call | No Complaints | 1 |
| 33 | x | 12c | 6 Months | 10/03/2020 | Clinic | No Complaints | 1 |
| 37 | z | 17q | 6 Months | 10/03/2021 | Call | Side Effects | 1 |

required data set:

|  |  |  | **6 Weeks** |  |  |  | **6 Months** |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RecNum | Hospital | Loction | FUpTime | FollowUpDate | FUType | Diagnosis | FUpTime | FollowUpDate | FUType |
| 12c | x | 1 | 6 Weeks | 10/09/2018 | Clinic | Side Effects | 6 Months | 10/03/2020 | Clinic |
| 16a | y | 2 | 6 Weeks | 22/11/2018 | Clinic | No Complaints | 6 Months | 15/06/2019 | Call |
| 17q | z | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6 Months | 10/03/2021 | Call |

Or required Data Set B:

| **RecNum** | **Hospital** | **Loction** | **FUpTime** | **FollowUpDate** | **FUType** | **Diagnosis** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12c | x | 1 | 6 Weeks | 10/09/2018 | Clinic | Side Effects |
| 12c | x | 1 | 6 Months | 10/03/2020 | Clinic | No Complaints |
| 16a | y | 2 | 6 Weeks | 22/11/2018 | Clinic | No Complaints |
| 16a | y | 2 | 6 Months | 15/06/2019 | Call | No Complaints |
| 17q | z | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 17q | z | 1 | 6 Months | 10/03/2021 | Call | Side Effects |

Comment: Please explain the logic.

Comment: For one unique "RecNum" , it must show two records i.e. for "6 Weeks"  and  For "6 months" with Max Id for each.

Comment: Please provide data and expected results as text in your question, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Dear @Stu , can't do better than this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used some common table expressions (`rn` and `fut`) to determine the unique `RecNum` and `FUpTime` values. You need a row for each combination, this can be achieved with a `cross join`. An `outer apply` can then fetch the required data for each combination (`top 1` and `order by d.Id desc`).

**Sample data**

```
create table Data
(
  Id int,
  Hospital nvarchar(1),
  RecNum nvarchar(3),
  FUpTime nvarchar(8),
  FollowUpDate date,
  FUType nvarchar(6),
  Diagnosis nvarchar(20),
  Loction int
);

insert into Data (Id, Hospital, RecNum, FUpTime, FollowUpDate, FUType, Diagnosis, Loction) values
(11, 'x', '12c', '6 Weeks' , '2017-03-14', 'Call',   'Side Effects',    1),
(18, 'y', '16a', '6 Weeks' , '2017-03-14', 'Call',   'No Complaints',   2),
(26, 'x', '12c', '6 Weeks' , '2018-09-10', 'Clinic', 'Side Effects',    1),
(27, 'y', '16a', '6 Weeks' , '2018-11-22', 'Clinic', 'No Complaints',   2),
(31, 'y', '16a', '6 Months', '2019-06-15', 'Call',   'No Complaints',   1),
(33, 'x', '12c', '6 Months', '2020-03-10', 'Clinic', 'No Complaints',   1),
(37, 'z', '17q', '6 Months', '2021-03-10', 'Call',   'Side Effects',    1);
```

**Solution**

```
with rn as
(
  select d.RecNum
  from Data d
  group by d.RecNum
),
fut as
(
  select d.FUpTime
  from Data d
  group by d.FUpTime
)
select rn.RecNum,
       dd.Hospital,
       dd.Loction,
       fut.FUpTime,
       dd.FollowUpDate,
       dd.FUType,
       dd.Diagnosis
from rn
cross join fut
outer apply ( select top 1
                     d.Hospital,
                     d.Loction,
                     d.FollowUpDate,
                     d.FUType,
                     d.Diagnosis
              from Data d
              where d.RecNum = rn.RecNum
                and d.FUpTime = fut.FUpTime
              order by d.Id desc ) dd
order by rn.RecNum,
         fut.FUpTime desc;
```

**Result**

```
RecNum  Hospital  Loction  FUpTime   FollowUpDate  FUType  Diagnosis
------  --------  -------  --------  ------------  ------  ---------
12c     x         1        6 Weeks   2018-09-10    Clinic  Side Effects
12c     x         1        6 Months  2020-03-10    Clinic  No Complaints
16a     y         2        6 Weeks   2018-11-22    Clinic  No Complaints
16a     y         1        6 Months  2019-06-15    Call    No Complaints
17q     null      null     6 Weeks   null          null    null
17q     z         1        6 Months  2021-03-10    Call    Side Effects
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=858f65e82218c294daa48b6aeec5c80a) to see things in action.

**Remarks**

This does not match 100% with "required data set B":

- `RecNum=16a, FUpTime=6 Months` = I have `Loction=1` here. If this was no typo on your end, then you will have to update your question with how you determine `Loction` on this row.
- `RecNum=17q, FUpTime=6 Weeks` = How do you determine `Hospital` and `Loction` when there is no corresponding row?

Also:

- Using three different abbreviations for "follow up" (`FUp`, `FU`, `FollowUp`) makes your data model confusing!
- Is `Loction` a incorrect spelling for `Location`?

Comment: Thank you @Sander for solution